# Display RichText into CKEditor using Lodash

Tags: jquery, django, ckeditor, richtext

I have added and edit functionality on my webpage. When a user clicks add, one of the fields is CKEditor.

But when the user clicks the Edit button I am currently using lodash template to setData() in the textarea of ckeditor but the text is unformatted. Please go through the following image.

**Current edit functionality when Edit is clicked upon which a modal opens** :-

[image]

**Desired functionality**:-

[image]

**My HTML page with Lodash**

```
<textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" value="<%- data.description %>"></textarea>
                  <script>
                      CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
                      val = "<%- data.description %>"
                      CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.setData(val);
                  </script>
```

Comment: It seems to me that you might to `decode html content`.

Comment: yes, can you please tell me how to do that?